# Join flat index with hierarchical indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, dataframe A:

```
               col1 
level1 level2
a      1         1
       2         2
b      1         3
       2         4
```

and dataframe B:

```
            col2
level1 
a           5
b           6
```

I want to join them to receive:

```
               col1 col2
level1 level2
a      1         1    5
       2         2    5
b      1         3    6
       2         4    6
```

In words, merge a single-level indexed dataframe into a hierarchical index dataframe. The missing values from the second level should be filled with copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look that general to me, and I believe their is a way to do a merge directly, though maybe not w/o modifying the 2nd frame (to make a merge key, e.g. this is kind of like cross merging).

```
In [49]: df1 = DataFrame({ 'A' : [1,2,3,4]})

In [50]: df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([ ('a',1),('a',2),('b',1),('b',2) ],names=['l1','l2'])

In [51]: df1
Out[51]: 
       A
l1 l2   
a  1   1
   2   2
b  1   3
   2   4

[4 rows x 1 columns]

In [52]: df2 = DataFrame({ 'B' : [5,6] },index=['a','b'])

In [53]: df2
Out[53]: 
   B
a  5
b  6

[2 rows x 1 columns]

In [54]: x, y = df1.align(df2,level='l1')

In [55]: x.combine_first(y)
Out[55]: 
       A  B
l1 l2      
a  1   1  5
   2   2  5
b  1   3  6
   2   4  6

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This might be of interest: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5401?source=cc

Comment: Works in the desired way. Thanks!